# Help with a 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I need some help with a htaccess 301 redirect.

I want to make a redirect from this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^author-details/([^/]+)-([^/]+).html$ /authors-details.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [QSA,L]
```

to this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-biography-([^/]+).html$ /authors-details.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^author-details/([0-9]+)-([^/]+).html$ http://your.host/$1-biography-$2.html [QSA,R=301]
```

or just

```
RewriteRule ^author-details/([0-9]+)-([^/]+).html$ $1-biography-$2.html [QSA,R=301]
```

[mod_rewrite reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Thanks Crack, but there's a little problem. The code above redirects to http://your.host/450-stephenie-biography-meyer.html which is not ok. The right URL is http://your.host/450-biography-stephenie-meyer.html

Comment: Try updated code and make sure that it's the new one that you are testing - browsers cache 301 redirects.